# Spring Boot + Hibernate changes case of column name when performing query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.1 and attempting to access a database wherein all column names are capitalized.  When performing a 'findAll' query via the repository, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property kitID found for type KittingEntity!
```

The query is structured like so:

```java
List<KittingEntity> kittingEntities =
                repository.getKittingRepository().findAll(
                        Sort.by(
                                new Sort.Order(
                                        Sort.Direction.ASC,
                                        KittingEntity.Constants.COLUMN_ID_NAME)));
```

The Entity class (relevant fields only) has the following structure:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = KittingEntity.Constants.TABLE_NAME, indexes = {
        @Index(name = "IX_Kitting_ProductID", columnList = "ProductID")
})
public class KittingEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6857112617148711718L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = Constants.COLUMN_ID_NAME, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static class Constants {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Kitting";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID_NAME = "KitID";
    }
}
```

It appears that Spring is changing my column names to camel case rather than using the annotation which specifies the correct column name.  Why is Spring changing my column name strings and how can I prevent this?

Here's the full PropertyReferenceException:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property kitID found for type KittingEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:601) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:781) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:761) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:440) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:84) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:638) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.conceptualsystems.SyncMessageGenerator.generateGetKitsResponse(SyncMessageGenerator.java:269) ~[tms-common-2.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.conceptualsystems.net.InboundHttpMessageProcessorServer.processHttpRequestMessage(InboundHttpMessageProcessorServer.java:100) [tms-common-2.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.conceptualsystems.net.InboundHttpMessageProcessorServer.processHttpMessage(InboundHttpMessageProcessorServer.java:45) [tms-common-2.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.conceptualsystems.mds.spring.MessageController.receiveMessage(MessageController.java:179) [classes!/:3.0.1]
    at com.conceptualsystems.mds.spring.MessageController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8758bac3.invoke(<generated>) [classes!/:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) [spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) [spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) [spring-tx-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) [spring-aop-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at com.conceptualsystems.mds.spring.MessageController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$911e6d90.receiveMessage(<generated>) [classes!/:3.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_351]
```

It looks like it passes through the PropertyPath initialization and calls `Introspector.decapitalize()`.  The naming strategy doesn't seem to affect this hard-coded case change.  I've tried the following naming strategies:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

And

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Comment: Mar-Z's answer is correct, and this is not a bug - You are mistaken in where and when the error is being caused by. This is not a DB SQL query error; you are using JPA entities, and are trying to sort on the Java entity's id property - it is accessible in JPQL and JPA criteria queries as "id" just as if you were using KittingEntity.id in the java object. Your mappings will automatically translate the queries to correctly use "KitID" in the SQL queries that are issued (assuming you haven't messed with the naming strategies; I agree, spring/hibernate changing column strings is a confusing pain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name attribute used in the `@Column` annotation is only applicable for the name of the database column. In JPA repository and in related queries, you should use the Java field names from the entity class.

In addition, JPA provides a bunch of predefined methods, which you can see in the [Spring Data JPA reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods). Following your example, you could get all kittings ordered ascending by id by using the JPA method:

```
List<KittingEntity> kittings = kittingsRepository.findAllOrderedByIdAsc();
```

Comment: This seems like bad design.  Why does Spring not use the "real" column name defined in the annotation when querying the database?  The real column name is already defined.  Why alter it, risking production of these errors?

Comment: I don't agree with you. Hibernate does use the column name for the queries marked as native. And of course for all DDL commands send to database. But for use in Java code the properties of the entity class are a better choice. The principle of ORM is to use Java code over the database internals.

Comment: if the database transaction fails, then it doesn't matter if it's convenient for use in Java.  There will be no data accessible because Spring is trying to access non-existent columns because it decapitalizes the column names.  If Spring can't use the correct column names, the data can never be mapped and it is unusable.  This is a bug.

Comment: The error you are getting does not come from the database but from the parameters you provided to the Sort.by(). You have provided a property name "KitID" which doesn't exist in the entity. The correct property name would be "id".